# What is most lightweight way of shuffle array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I purpose the most lightweight way (from performance point of view) to shuffle an array is

```js
document.write([1, 2, 3, 4].sort(function() {
    return 0.5 - Math.random();
}));
```

Isn't it?

Comment: Nope, you have nxn complexity due to sorting, while these solutions iterate only once http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array ... maybe yours can be the shortest one :)

Comment: That is also a non-consistent comparator. I wonder if depending on the sort algorithm used that would result in problems. For example, in Java, you can get run-time-exceptions with that.

Comment: Duplicate of this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18650169/14955 (with a couple of comments on why this method is quite bad).